# forwarding postfix virtual mailbox to gmail

Tags: postfix, email

I want postfix to forward one of the emails on my domain to gmail.
Virtual settings:

```
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

virtual contains the following (actual values replaced):

```
user1@domain.com domain.com/user1/
user2@domain.com domain.com/user2/
user3@domain.com user3@gmail.com
```

This works for the local maildirs.
Emails to the 3rd user i want forwarding to a gmail account.

---

However when a message is sent to `user3@domain.com`, instead of forwarding the mail on to gmail, postfix creates a `user3@gmail.com` file in `/home/vmail` with the contents of the email (maybe in mbox format??)

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to add an alias, aliases are specified using virtual_alias_maps, not virtual_mailbox_maps. Have a look at http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps